# How to make min() function in php

Tags: php, function

How to make `min()` function 
I found some functions but they don't really work

like this function

```
$my_array= [ 10 , 20 ,300,5,2,3,4 ,12 , 3232];

function minNum($array){
$min = $temp = 0;

for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($array); $i++) {
   if ($i == 0) {
        $min = $temp = $array[$i];
        
   }
   if ($i > 0) {
       if ($array[$i] < $temp) {
         
             $min = $array[$i];

       }
   }
}
    return $min;
}

echo minNum($my_array);
```

this function will output 
`4`

and you should know why it return `4` not `2`

I make function depends on other built-in function :

```
$my_array= [ 10 , 20 ,300,5,2,3,4 ,12 , 3232];

function minNum($array){
sort($array);

$firstlain = array_shift($array);
echo $firstlain;
}

minNum($my_array);
```

but this not what I want I want function depends on loops and conditions not on other functoin 
so.... any ideas ??

Comment: Why can't you just use `min(array)`?

Comment: @Marwelln pretty sure he wants to learn. I get these answers a lot too - "why won't you do that", so I started mentioning that it's for educational purposes. I still get downvoted on these questions a lot. Sometimes I really don't understand SO.

Comment: @Marwelln *I want function depends on loops and conditions not on other functoin
so*

Answer (score 1):

In your first function, you test against `$temp`, but set the minimum value only in `$min`.  If you just have 1 variables it will work..

```
function minNum($array){
    $min = 0;
    for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($array); $i++) {
        if ($i == 0) {
            $min = $array[$i];
        }
        else if ($array[$i] < $min) {
            $min = $array[$i];
        }
    }
    return $min;
}
```

to be able to remove the extra condition for the the first loop, you can set min to be the largest integer to start with instead...

```
function minNum($array){
    $min = PHP_INT_MAX;
    for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($array); $i++) {
        if ($array[$i] < $min) {
            $min = $array[$i];
        }
    }
    return $min;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple function;

```
$my_array= [ 10 , 20 ,300,5,2,3,4 ,12 , 3232];

function minNum($array)
{
    foreach($array as $v)$min = (empty($min) || $min>$v ? $v:$min);
        return $min;
}

echo minNum($my_array);
```

making it even simpler;

```
function minNum($array)
{
    sort($array);
    return current($array);
}
```